# Inserting a link into an image in matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, hyperlink

I want to put a link to a document in an image I have in matlab. I have a specific region I want to put the link. For example I want there to be link in the image at position x = 40, y = 120 with the address of the document. Something similar to this below, I know this is not proper matlab code.

```
text(40,120, '<a href="C:\Documents and Settings\Sentinelle\Desktop\LCModel\sl5_knt1\sl5_11-6.pdf"; ">Click here for plot documentation</a>')
```

Is this possible to do do? I want to be able to use imshow() or imtool() and be able to click on the region of the image and see the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the [`'ButtonDownFcn'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/text_props.html#ButtonDownFcn) text property to open the given document using the function [OPEN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/open.html):

```
filePath = 'C:\Documents and Settings\Sentinelle\Desktop\LCModel\sl5_knt1\sl5_11-6.pdf';
text(40,120,'Click here for plot documentation',...
     'ButtonDownFcn',['open(''' filePath ''');']);
```

Comment: I like the idea but I am getting this error 
    ??? Error using ==> open
    Too many input arguments.
 
    ??? Error while evaluating text ButtonDownFcn

Comment: @Ben: Oh, I see. Your file path has spaces in it. I'll edit to account for that.

Answer (score 3):

According to a similar [discussion](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/164962), you can create a [UICONTROL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uicontrol.html) `pushbutton` which has the advantage that it accepts HTML input string. Then using [FINDJOBJ](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14317-findjobj-find-java-handles-of-matlab-graphic-objects), we can fake the look of a clickable hyperlink:

```
fName = 'C:\path\to\file.pdf';
str = '<html><a href="">Click here for plot documentation</a></html>';

figure('Resize','off', 'MenuBar','none')
imshow('coins.png')
hButton = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton', 'Position',[320 50 170 20], ...
    'String',str, 'Callback',@(o,e)open(fName));

jButton = findjobj(hButton);
jButton.setCursor( java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR) );
jButton.setContentAreaFilled(0);
```

[image: screenshot]