# Inserting multiple links into an image in Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, hyperlink

This question is built off of this previous question [`'here'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932128/inserting-a-link-into-an-image-in-matlab) I want to make 256 points on the image that all lead to different pdf documents based on the location of the *. I dont want to have to code in 256 separate filepaths. I have attempted some code below and have not been having any luck so far.

```
for i = 1:256

    text(x(i),y(i),'*', 'ButtonDownFcn',['open(''' file ''');']);
end

function [filePath] = file()
    %h = impoint;
    %position = getPosition(h);

    filePath = strcat('C:\Documents and Settings\Sentinelle\Desktop\LCModel\sl5_knt1\sl5_',x(1),'-',y(i),'.pdf');
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that your code is wrong in several places:

1. the `file()` function doesn't know the values of `x` and `y`
2. the `file()` function doesn't use the current value of `i`
3. the file path uses `x(1)` idependently of the value of `i`

You probably want

```
for i = 1:256
    text(x(i), y(i), '*', 'ButtonDownFcn', ['open(''' file(x(i),y(i)) ''');']);
end

function [filePath] = file( x, y )
    filePath = strcat('C:\Documents and Settings\Sentinelle\Desktop\LCModel\sl5_knt1\sl5_',x,'-',y,'.pdf');
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming x(i) and y(i) are integers, this should work:

```
prefix = 'C:\Documents and Settings\Sentinelle\Desktop\LCModel\sl5_knt1\sl5_'
for i = 1:256
  filePath = [prefix num2str(x(i)) '-' num2str(y(i)) '.pdf'];
  text(x(i),y(i),'*', 'ButtonDownFcn',['open(''' filePath ''');']);
end
```

If they aren't integers, you need to specify how the floating point number will be converted to a string. You can do that with the second argument of num2str, type:

```
help num2str
```

for details and browse from there.