# MATLAB Adding hyperlinks to a text string

Tags: matlab, hyperlink

I am trying to add a hyperlink to a text output. I have the following lines of text:

```
text_msg1 = ['Detected Door Alarm sensor trips'];
text_msg2 = ['Please click on link to view trends'];
text_msg3 = [' http://www.google.com '];
text = strcat(text_msg1,'.',text_msg2,':',text_msg3);
```

When I print text, the web address does not show as hyperlink. Instead it appears as plain text. I tried using the following trick to display the hyperlink. But this only works in command line.

```
text_msg3 = '<a href="matlab:web(''https://www.google.com/'');">Link</a>';
```

However, the link only works in the command line. I have an application that sends a text message to a technician. The text in the email does not show the hyperlink. I don't know how I could share the application in this forum.

Comment: Hello @m7913d, I edited my post above. please review.

Comment: How do you send the message? Is it an HTML message or just plain text? I guess that you should write `'<a href="https://www.google.com/">Link</a>';`

Comment: "However, the link only works in the command line." Where/how else are you trying this? Show the case where it doesn't work. Is `disp(text);` what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, HTML hyperlinks like the one you are using do not work at all in figures. It is possible to recreate the functionality of a hyperlink with some scripting, however. [Here is one example of that](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/291484). [Here's another possibility that makes use of the same premise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6932204/4808244).